# Issue with GetProcessImageFileNameA, buffer size insufficient

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using GetProcessImageFileNameA [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getprocessimagefilenamea).  I want to get the file path to an executable currently running.  However, I keep getting an error of insufficient space in buffer (error code 122) that it is writing the path to.  I have a handle opened and such. Any help is appreciated:

```
namespace proc{
    static LPSTR exeName[MAX_PATH]; 
};


//  Inside another function I am calling GetProcessImageFileNameA as such:


if (GetProcessImageFileNameA(proc::currentHandle, proc::exeName[i], sizeof(*proc::exeName[i])) == 0)
{

}
```

Comment: `GetProcessImageFileNameA(proc::currentHandle, proc::exeName[i], sizeof(*proc::exeName[i])) == 0)` -- Why are you passing a single character as the second argument?  What does that `sizeof` accomplish in the third parameter?  The API document is quite clear as to what to pass to it, but you're not following the documentation carefully w.r.t the C++ language.

Comment: The code is not passing a single character in the 2nd parameter, but it is passing the size of a single character in the 3rd parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that exeName contains a list of pointers to a buffer, that the function then writes to.  So exeName[0] would be the actual pointer to the buffer, not an actual single character.  The documentation says for the second param, it is a pointer to a buffer.  If I pass proc::exeName as the second param, I get an error "type LPSTR* is incompatible with param of type LPSTR".  What should I be passing instead?  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @DreamingJ if you declare `exeName` as an array of pointers, then yes, you would have to pass `exeName[index]` as the buffer to fill, but you are still responsible for making that pointer actually point at valid allocated memory beforehand, which the code you showed is not doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your buffering is wrong.  You have created an array of uninitialized pointers, and are passing the size of a single character as the buffer size to `GetProcessImageFileNameA()`.  There is nowhere for it to write the data to, even if the size were large enough, which it is not.

Try this instead:

```
namespace proc{
    static char exeName[MAX_PATH]; 
};

...

GetProcessImageFileNameA(proc::currentHandle, proc::exeName, sizeof(proc::exeName))
```

Or, if you really did need an array of strings:

```
namespace proc{
    static char exeName[SOME_MAX_COUNT][MAX_PATH]; 
};

...

GetProcessImageFileNameA(proc::currentHandle, proc::exeName[index], sizeof(proc::exeName[index]))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for clarifying.  I understand now.  I saw that you changed the array type to char from LPSTR.  In the documentation I saw it should be LPSTR.  I'll look up the difference between the two.  When I used LPSTR and I tried to do the above, such as proc::exename[index], I would get an error of LPSTR* incompatible with type LPSTR.  I made an array of strings, to clarify this would be an array of SOME_MAX_COUNT strings each with size MAX_PATH?  Thank you :)

Comment: You must pass an allocated buffer for `GetProcessImageFileNameA()` to fill in. The 2nd param is a pointer to the buffer, and the 3rd param is the allocated size of the buffer.  A fixed array *decays* into a pointer to its first element. `LPSTR` is just an alias for `char*`. You can pass an allocated `char[]` where a `char*` is expected. My 1st example creates 1 `char[MAX_PATH]` string buffer. My 2nd example creates an array of `SOME_MAX_COUNT` `char[MAX_PATH]` string buffers. Either way, only 1 `char[]` is passed to `GetProcessImageFileNameA()` at a time.